# Doubt with antiderivatives in complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having lectures in complex variables, I have the following doubt in the following theorem:

> [image]

This seems to suggest that I can test if $f$ has an antiderivative, then I can compute $\int_\gamma f(z) \,dz =0$ along some closed contour. But then I pick the parametrization of that curve and write:

$$\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = \int_{a}^{b} f(z(t))z'(t) \, dz \tag{$\star$}$$

And check if it equals zero. What confuses me is the following: If I don't know that $f$ has an antiderivative, what is the point in that? In the following sense: If $f$ doesn't has an antiderivative, then I won't be able to compute $(\star)$ because I can't find $F$ such that $F'=f$, right? Or is it the case that finding an antiderivative of $\int_\gamma f(z) \,dz =0$ is something different of computing $\int_{a}^{b} f(z(t))z'(t) \, dz$?

I was thinking that $f$ not having an antiderivative would inhibit me from computing $\int_{a}^{b} f(z(t))z'(t) \, dz$ but I suspect that might not be the case at all.

Comment: Perhaps the example $f(z) = 1/z$, $S= \{z \in \mathbb{C}, 0 < |z| < 1\}$ will illuminate the situation?

Comment: That statement seems to be false if nothing else is said about the nature of the domain S....

Comment: @DonAntonio the theorem statement looks right as it is. Sure, without further information, not every holomorphic function on $S$ has an anti-derivative (eg $\frac{1}{z}$ in $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$), but that doesn't invalidate the statement of the theorem.

Comment: @DonAntonio The author gives conditions for that previously. I just chose to not copy everything but the conditions are the reasonable conditions anyone would expect for a basic course in complex variables (supposing that actually exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they say $f$ has an antiderivative, they mean there is a function $F(z)$ such that $F'(z) = f(z)$ for each $z$ in the entire domain. This is distinct from computing the integral along a particular path, which is still possible even if the function has no "global" antiderivative

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ doesn't have any antiderivative in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. However, we still can compute the integral $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz$ when $\gamma$ is the unit circle. We have the parametrization $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{C}$, $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$. Then:

$\int_{\gamma} f(z)=dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}}ie^{it}dt=2\pi i$

So while $f$ doesn't have an antiderivative in general, specifically on the image of $\gamma$ it is a very simple function, and we can easily compute the integral.

Comment: I think I get it. But then, what is the meaning of "having an antiderivative"? I'm still thinking it like calculus, where "an antiderivative" means a function that can be written in terms of finite elementary functions by means of elementary operations and composition. I am a bit aware that we can speak about $g(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(x) \,dx$ as a function in it's own right even if we can't find $F$ such that $F'=f$ and $F$ can be written in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @RedBanana To be explicit, *no* mathematician/math text means "have an elementary antiderivative" when they write "has an antiderivative"; see Rob Bland's answer. And writing antiderivatives as integrals should be less taken for granted in complex analysis; there are theorems about when it can be done and how (since there are many paths from $a$ to $x$ in the plane).

Comment: @RedBanana An antiderivative in a domain $G$ is just a holomorphic function $F$ such that $F'=f$ in all $G$. It doesn't have to be an elementary function. Note that the definition of the integral $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$ doesn't contain the word antiderivative. If $f$ has an antiderivative in a domain which contains $\gamma$ then it can help us compute the integral. But it doesn't mean we can't compute it if $f$ doesn't have an antiderivative. Because again, we care only about how $f$ behaves on the image of $\gamma$, not in the whole domain $G$.